# How to run racket in sublime text?

Tags: racket, package

I installed Sublime Text - Racket Package, but it didn't work. This error shows up. What should I do.

```
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'racket'
    [cmd: ['racket', '/Users/ZweNaing/Desktop/DrRacket/addDash.rkt']]
    [dir: /Users/ZweNaing/Desktop/DrRacket]
    [path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
    [Finished]
```

Comment: On Windows with WSL, this might be caused by Sublime not running your WSL shell, but rather whatever is the default shell (maybe cmd.exe), and thus not having Racket in its PATH env var.

Answer (score 5):

First find the path where racket is installed. If you are using DrRacket it should be in a folder called `bin` beside the DrRacket app.

For example, the path is

`/Applications/Racket v6.6/bin` for me.

Then go to "Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings – User":

and add the following line:

```
"additional_path_items": ["/Applications/Racket v6.6/bin"],
```

or whatever your path is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error is still happening and still can't build. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: Are you using macOS, Linux, or, Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Sublime is trying to run the 'racket' program from the command line but can't find it. You can resolve this by creating a symbolic link to the application binary. For example, on mac OS, if you've downloaded the application from the [official site](https://download.racket-lang.org/) and copied it into your Applications folder as directed, you would run:

```
ln -sf /Applications/Racket\ v7.4/bin/racket /usr/local/bin/racket
```

Replace the version number 'v7.4' with whichever version you have.

You should be able to confirm that this worked by running `racket --version` in the terminal. Note that mac OS will probably try to stop you from opening it because of the security settings, so you'll have to go to 'Security & Privacy' to 'allow' the program to run.